# Get a variable declared into eval command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to use a variable initialized into a subscript, in order to avoid returning it with `echo` or `return`.

For example, my goal is to output $myvar with this script:

```
eval "./script.sh"
echo -n $myvar
```

declared inside script.sh like this:

```
declare -gx myvar # global and exported var
myvar=42
```

**Output:**

nothing

Is there another command or flag to add in replacement to `declare -gx` ? Or moving it before `eval` is the solution ?

Comment: Try `source "./script.sh"`. Or, even shorter, `". ./script.sh"`.

Comment: To make `eval` do you wanted, it'd need to be `eval "$(<./script.sh)"`, or `eval "$(cat ./script.sh)"` -- but those are both very silly, as `source` Does The Right Thing out-of-the-box.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `declare -gx` at all here. `declare -g` is only needed when you're inside a function. `declare -x` is only needed when you want the variable exported to subprocesses. Neither situation applies.

Comment: Thank you very much for responses, it works, but unfortunately not with aliases

Comment: Nobody should ever use aliases. They're worse than shell functions in every way. (There are actually some exceptions, but if you're not enough of an expert to already know what they are, they don't apply to you).

Answer (score 0):

You can use source instead of eval:

```
source "./script.sh"
```

Comment: It works great thanks, but now what if I need to use a script with an alias ? The source command does not match aliases

Comment: @RDKHEN, by default, aliases don't work inside scripts at all. (There's a reason the freenode #bash channel advice about aliases is "if you need to ask, use a function instead").

Comment: Ok then, so I will only use scrpts since now, thank you

Comment: You don't need to *only* use scripts. *Shell functions* serve the use case aliases do, but do so more effectively; and they work the same way in your interactive shell (f/e, defined in `.bashrc`) as they do in a script.

Comment: Used source inside a function, and called it, and now I can find my variable, it's great